# Migrating Sandbox changes to Production - Professional Edition

Tags: sandbox, migration, professional-edition, production

I am looking for a way to migrate the changes I made in my sandbox into my production environment..  I am using the Professional Edition, which adds a  level of complexity.

Please advise.

Comment: How do you have a sandbox for a Professional org? Is it really a Developer org?

Comment: It sounds to me like maybe you have a DE org that you are making changes to, but your production org is PE. When you login to your sandbox org, what URL do you go to? Do you use login.salesforce.com? Do you use test.salesforce.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professional and Group Editions do not support the Metadata API needed to deploy configuration changes from one place to another. [(API Access in Group and Professional Editions)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm)

> Other APIs such as the Metadata API, Bulk API, and Apex Methods
>   exposed using the SOAP Web service remain unavailable.

The only true workaround I know for this is to create a managed package and have it go through security review and such.

Comment: My production org is Professional.  I use test.salesforce.com for sandbox.    (bad advice from SF rep)  How do I create a managed package?  Has anyone used Eclipse Force IDE or
Ant Script

Comment: You can't use the migration tools like Eclipse, MavensMate, ANT, etc. They all operate off API's that are not exposed in Professional Edition. You literally cannot do what you are trying to do if your prod org is indeed Professional Edition (as you have stated).

I've personally never dealt with Managed Packages so I can't really steer you in any direction there. I can tell you that whatever package you created would have to be submitted for security review and such though.